# Marketing Cloud Roles & Visibility, if allow and deny are not checked this means that it is not visible?

Tags: marketing-cloud, administration, security, roles

When setting up users in their respective roles, if the allow and deny boxes are not checked this means that the feature/capability is not visible to them correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means the user does not have access. In order to a User have access, the allow must be checked, if it is not checked, then the user will not have access.

When the deny box is checked, this means the user (or role) access is explicit denied, basicly eventhough if another role "check" the allow box, the access (or permission) will still be denied.

Comment: Thanks a lot Leto, makes sense.